# Wrong data is coming from Observable service in Angular 10

Tags: angular, observable, ionic4

I have created an application in angular using ionic. In a component I have called three service to get data, which I am showing in UI. I have used Observable and subscribe in service.ts. But the problem is, in UI I am generating multiple checkbox with the data, only check box are coming text is not showing and tried to console the data and find it's printing data of other service randomly which I calling in same component. I am not able to figure out the problem. Code which i have used:

```
<ion-col *ngFor="let item of Product;" size-xl="3" size-lg="3" size-md="4" size-sm="12" size-xs="12">
              <ion-item>
                <ion-checkbox value="{{item.ProductID}}" (ionChange)="selectProduct($event)"></ion-checkbox>
                <ion-label>{{item.Product}}</ion-label>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
```

Service:-

```
getProduct(): Observable<Product> {
    const params = new HttpParams()
        .set('id', '');
    return this.http.get<Product>(this.apiBaseUrl + '/product/get?' + params)
        .pipe(
            retry(1),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        );
}
```

Component:-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ProductService } from '../../service/product.service';
import { AgentService } from '../../service/agent.service';
import { DesignationService } from '../../service/designation.service';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-buyer-register',
   templateUrl: './buyer-register.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./buyer-register.component.scss'],
 })
export class BuyerRegisterComponent implements OnInit {
 public formBuyer: FormGroup;
 Product: any = [];
 public selectedProduct: any = [];
 Designation: any = [];
 Agent: any = [];

 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private productService: 
  ProductService, private agentService: AgentService, 
  private designationService: DesignationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.loadProduct();
   this.loadAgent();
   this.loadDesignation();
  }

  loadProduct() {
    this.productService.getProduct().subscribe(data => {
    this.Product = data;
    console.log(this.Product);
  });
 }

 loadAgent() {
    this.agentService.getAgent().subscribe(data => this.Agent = data);
 }

 loadDesignation() {
    this.designationService.getDesignation().subscribe(data => {
      this.Designation = data;
   });
 }  
}
```

Console Log:-
[image]

But some time it's returning correct data and sometime it's returning data from different service.

Output in UI:
[image]

Comment: Please show the whole component.

Comment: @MichaelD added the whole component.